# Graph theory undirected graph problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph , $|V|=n \ge 3$, n is Even.
and $deg(v)\ge (n-1)/2$
$$$$
i need to show that G is an Hamilton graph... im here with about 5 other students... and no one has any clue... can someone please help me or show me a way to solve this problem? thank you!

Comment: Check out https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac's_Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple

By Dirac (1952) :

> A simple graph with n vertices ($n ≥ 3$) is
>   Hamiltonian if every vertex has degree $\frac{n}{2}$ or greater. See
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Since n is even, then 2 does **not** divides $n-1$. Thus $$d(v)\geq \frac{n}{2}$$